# Lime Explainer: ValueError: training data did not have the following fields

Tags: machine-learning, classification, xgboost

I'm attempting to gather ID level drivers from my XGBoost classification model using LIME and I'm running into some odd errors. I'm using this [link](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2017/06/building-trust-in-machine-learning-models/) as a reference.

Here is the overall code that I'm using:

```
explainer = lime.lime_tabular.LimeTabularExplainer(Xs_train.values, class_names = [1.0, 0.0], kernel_width = 3)

predict_fn_xgb = lambda x: trained_model.predict_proba(x).astype(float)
data_point = Xs_val.values[5]

exp = explainer.explain_instance(data_point, predict_fn_xgb, num_features = 10)
exp.show_in_notebook(show_all = False)
```

Key:

- trained_model: trained xgboost classification model
- class names: This is a binary classification model
- Xs_train: This is a (73548, 84) dimension training set. This was used to build the training_model
- Xs_val: This is a (4910, 84) dimension training set. The columns are the same with the training and validation set.
- data_point: one specific validation point

Now, when I run this code, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: expected res_time, email_views...training data did not have the following fields: f6, f49, f34, f21,...
```

I don't know where the `f#` column names are coming from. Seems really bizarre and I believe I'm following the example correctly.

Any help would be much appreciated. Let me know if any additional information is required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like a dataframe/nparray mismatch.  Probably your model was trained on a dataframe; doing the training instead on an nparray may fix the problem.

I've seen such errors in working with xgboost; see e.g.
https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/2334 and
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52578211/10495893